# What's wrong with my Wapiti commandline?

Tags: wapiti

I'm using this command:

```
    wapiti.exe http://localhost/mysite/mypage.asp -v 2 -c blah.json
```

And I get this output:

```
    Wapiti-2.3.0 (wapiti.sourceforge.net)
    Exception in lswww.browse: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

     Note
    ========
    This scan has been saved in the file C:\Users\Michael\.wapiti\scans/localhost.xml
    You can use it to perform attacks without scanning again the web site with the "-k" parameter
    [*] Loading modules:
             mod_crlf, mod_exec, mod_file, mod_sql, mod_xss, mod_backup, mod_htaccess, mod_blindsql, mod_permanentxss, mod_nikto

    [+] Launching module exec

    [+] Launching module file

    [+] Launching module sql

    [+] Launching module xss

    [+] Launching module blindsql

    [+] Launching module permanentxss

    Report
    ------
    A report has been generated in the file C:\Users\Michael\.wapiti\generated_report
    Open C:\Users\Michael\.wapiti\generated_report/index.html with a browser to see this report.
```

The report is basically empty because Wapiti doesn't do anything due to the exception.

If I leave off the -c parameter (i.e. the cookie file) it does a scan, but I presume isn't ever going to see anything deeper than the logon page because our app uses forms authentication and has basically no public content.

I had previously used wapiti-getcookie.exe to do a successful authentication to our app and then save the cookies to blah.json - it appears to be filled with useful stuff, so I'm a bit puzzled.

Time to learn how to debug Python?

Comment: Did you find the reason?

Comment: Kind of, I changed operating systems and it worked.  I was trying to do this under Windows 7 but finally gave in and installed Kali Linux on a USB stick.  My Linux is rusty but within half an hour I was successfully running Wapiti, Nikto and SQLMap.  Clearly Windows is not the security professional's OS of choice!

Answer (score 1):

not sure but it can help for someone. I was receiving the same results until I launched cmd with Admin rights. After this I typed ***wapiti.exe {my-web-site}*** and it started to scan it.